# bash/linux: FIND - FFMPEG for batch, how remove extention of file (format) for FIND and FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, find

i wish to remove the format of file for FFMPEG but i need command FIND, i use IF,ELIF, ELSE IF..

```
fortmat4find='.avi'
format4output='mp4'
....
....if....; then...
.....else sh -c "find . -iname $format4find -exec ffmpeg -n -i {} {}-CONVERTED$format4output \;";
fi;
```

file original: AAA.avi
result output from ffmpeg (works): AAA.avi-CONVERTED.mp4

i want will be result like this: **`AAA-CONVERTED.mp4`**

how remove extension of file by command:FIND

note: i want not to use command: FOR,

i don't find in google for remove the extension in ffmpeg with command find...
so i need how to remove extension of file by command:FIND
for bash file sh
note: i want not to use command: FOR,

Comment: i found SOLUTION: